# Efficiency: Func<T>, Vs instance of T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, functional-programming

Recently I've been experimenting with the use of the `Func<T>` class, and so far I'm loving it. I've noticed however that more and more I'm beginning to use it instead of actually using an instance of `T`, so I wanted to ask; **what's the overhead of using `Func<T>` vs `T`?** I know this is a somewhat generic question, as `T` can be anything, so I guess that question should maybe be focused towards, **what is the overhead of passing a function, rather than an instance of a simple object?**

For the sake of argument, let's assume the following.

### Our mock object, `T`

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private int _age = 0;
    private bool _isMale = true;

    public Person(string name, int age, bool isMale)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.IsMale = isMale;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return this._age; }
        set { this._age = value; }
    }

    public bool IsMale
    {
        get { return this._isMale; }
        set { this._isMale = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say we have a pretty extension method on `IDictionary`, that selects the value by the key, *or* a default value. The pseudocode could be described as follows:
Is the key found in the KeyValuePair collection
   Yes, return the value
No, return the default

### Option 1. Our extension method using an instance of `T`

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary source, TKey key, TValue @default)
{
    if (source.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return source[key];
    }
    return @default;
}

// usage
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", new Person());
```

### Option 2. Our extension method using `Func<T>`... mmm, pretty!

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary source, TKey key, Func<TValue> defaultSelector)
{
    if (source.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return source[key];
    }
    return defaultSelector();
}

// usage
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", () => new Person("Richard", 25, true));
```

### Comparison

Comparing the above options, it's clear that there are potential benefits of both. Option 1 is slightly easier to read, however I'm currently *loving* the usage of `Func<T>`, and therefore to me option 2 seems ideal. I guess I'm considering it a lazily-instantiated parameter, that is only executed when it's needed, therefore saving on efficiency, but am I right?

Comment: If you really dig Func<T>, you should look into F# - the syntax is much cleaner for functional programming and F# has its own FastFunc type for better performance. It's also awesome in a number of other ways :)

Comment: I disagree. Beyond the simplest code `F#` becomes impossible to read as it relies on obscure semantics (have the right braces, brackets and pipes). It looks more like LISP than anything else.

Comment: @ja72 Care to elaborate? What obscure semantics are you talking about? And what do you mean by "have the right braces, brackets and pipes"? Thanks.

Comment: Somebody got syntax (braces, brackets, and vertical bar characters) confused with semantics (behavior).

Comment: @ja27 For functional programming specifically, it's rather C# that gets unreadable quickly - Func<T, Func<U, Func<T, U>>> etc. F# remains terse and readable due to better type inference.

Reading F# takes some getting used to, but so does C#...

Comment: @Dr_Asik: Ben get it right. I confused semantics with syntax.

Comment: auto implemented properties are great, especially for sample code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code I used for the benchmark:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Numerics;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    public class Program
    {

        public class Person
        {
            private string _name = string.Empty;

            private int _age = 0;

            private bool _isMale = true;

            public Person(string name, int age, bool isMale)
            {
                this.Name = name;
                this.Age = age;
                this.IsMale = isMale;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._name;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._name = value;
                }
            }

            public int Age
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._age;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._age = value;
                }
            }

            public bool IsMale
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._isMale;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._isMale = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
            myDictionary.Add("notRichard", new Program.Person("Richard1", 26, true));
            myDictionary.Add("notRichard1", new Program.Person("Richard2", 27, true));
            myDictionary.Add("notRichard2", new Program.Person("Richard3", 28, true));
            myDictionary.Add("notRichard3", new Program.Person("Richard4", 29, true));
            // usage
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", new Program.Person("Richard", 25, true));
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", ()=> new Program.Person("Richard", 25, true));
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public static class Ex
    {
        public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, TValue @default)
        {
            if (source.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return source[key];
            }
            return @default;
        }
        public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, Func<TValue> defaultSelector)
        {
            if (source.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return source[key];
            }
            return defaultSelector();
        }


    }
}
```

Calling each extenssion method **100000000** times (without finding an entry, hence causing Func to be executed each time) gives the following result:

`T` - 10352 ms

`Func<T>` - 12268 ms

Calling each extenssion method **100000000** times (and finding an entry, hence not calling Func at all) gives the following result:

`T` - 15578 ms

`Func<T>` - 11072 ms

Hence, which one performs quicker depends of how many instantiations you save and how expensive is each instantiation.

Optimising the code a bit by reusing the default person instance gives 6809 ms for `T` and 7452 for `Func<T>`:

```
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            var defaultPerson = new Program.Person("Richard", 25, true);
            sw.Start();
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", defaultPerson);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", () => defaultPerson);
            }
```

So, in theory (if you take instantiation out of the equation), saving a hop in the call stack gives you some performance gain, but in practice, this gain is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a reference to a function and passing a reference to an object I would expect to be very similar. If you are doing a million of these calls, both would probably benefit by saving the reference on the side, and reusing the same value every time. But notice that in the first case, the default object can be made the same every time:

```
Person defaultPerson = new Person();
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", defaultPerson);
```

but in the second case, you would be instantiating a brand new `Person` every time a default was returned:

```
Func<Person> defaultPersonFunc = () => new Person("Richard", 25, true);
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", defaultPersonFunc);
```

You could get around that by changing to:

```
Person defaultPerson = new Person("Richard", 25, true);
Func<Person> defaultPersonFunc = () => defaultPerson;
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", defaultPersonFunc);
```

but then I don't see that you would be gaining anything by using the `Func<Person>`

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are great, but I'm not sure this is a situation where you benefit from using them.

Option 1 is inefficient because you create a new object instance unconditionally:

```
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", new Person());
```

a new Person is always created.

Option 2 is inefficient because you create a new `Func` instance. Your syntax is shorthand for this:

```
var myValue = myDictionary.GetValueOrDefault("Richard", new Func<Person>(()=> {
    Person("Richard", 25, true));
});
```

It's possible the compiler may optimize one more than the other, but ultimately, this is a case of using the wrong tool to solve the problem. The solution is to use the built-in `TryGetValue` method and *actually* run the default code only when needed:

```
Person myValue;
if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue("Richard", out myValue)) {
    myValue = new Person("Richard",25,true);
}
```

Running the tests from the other answer I get for when the target is not in the dictionary:

- 7309 ms (opt 1)
- 8705 ms (opt 2)
- 5972 ms (TryGetValue)

For when the target is in the dictionary (e.g. it never needs to use the default value):

- 10026 ms (opt 2)
- 7712 ms (opt 2)
- 3491 ms (TryGetValue)

It's clearly substantially faster no matter what. This makes sense - since you have to create an object no matter what the outcome *every time* you do the test for either option 1 or 2. In the `Func` scenario, you have to create *two* objects when the default is needed and one when it's not, hence it's faring worst when the default is always needed.

On the other hand, just using `TryGetValue` and only conditionally executing the default code, you only need to create an object (and just the one you really need) when the default is needed.

Sometimes the old fashioned way is the best :)

FWIW - I think that a method like `GetValueOrDefault` is certainly useful, but perhaps not when you have to explicitly define the default value. That is, I don't see a tremendous benefit in terms of the code style to using a delegate, and there's certainly no performance benefit. But if you don't need to actually define the contents of the default person, then why not just create an extension method like this:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary source, 
    TKey key) where TValue: new()
{
    TValue value;
    if (!source.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
        value = new TValue();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I agree, and disagree with some points in this answer, but I do appreciate your input, greatly! As my question states, the overhead of creating an instance of `T` is variant, therefore there will be times when creating an instance of `T` will be greater than creating an instance of `Func<T>`, and vice versa. The `TryGetValue` solution is elegant, but I'd maybe add an extension method with an `Action<T>` that handles failures. I should have also mentioned that this is also being used objects such as the view state, which doesn't have `TryGetValue`. :)

Comment: Well, if you are trying to create code that's efficient, using an inline delegate is not the right way to do it. It may be better or worse than creating the actual `T`, but it's always worse than not creating anything.   It doesn't matter if you have a TryGetValue method or not. Obviously you have a way to test for the existence of a member in a  collection. In both of your options you do work that you don't need to before actually seeing if you need to do it or not. You're trying to avoid using an `if`. There's no reason to!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wonder how effective it would be to use my `GetValueOrDefault` and wrap the `TryGetValue`... hmm.

Comment: I just tried that actually :) it does close the gap a little bit but the win/place/show are the same: 7334/9071/5900 for not in dict, 7488/5216/3490 for in dict.

Comment: Bear in mind of course that the unless you are in a loop with tens of millions of iterations these performance differences will never matter. But it's more a question of general approach to programming logic. You're trying to shoehorn a logic construct into a fluent language construct. I understand the appeal, but it's not the right approach. While it may not matter much for serving up a few hundred web pages every minute, you just shouldn't be in the habit of ignoring these kinds of issues when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is inefficient because it requires the compiler to generate a closure (a combination of a delegate and an object instance) every time the function is called, regardless of whether the closure will actually be needed.  Unless `Person` is expensive to create, unconditionally generating a closure will be worse than unconditionally generating a `Person`.

An alternative approach would be to have the lambda be a static method which accepts its parameters as a ref struct.  I wish C# would provide some language support for this approach, because it can do many of the things closures can do, more efficiently.  The code would look something like:

```
public delegate TResult TFuncByRef<TParam,TResult>(ref TParam);
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue, TParam>
  (this IDictionary source, TKey key, 
   FuncByRef<TParam, TValue> defaultSelector, 
   ref TParam param)
{
    ref TValue Result = default(TValue);
    if (!source.TryGetValue(key, ref Result))
        Result = defaultSelector(ref param);
    return Result;
}

struct CreatePersonParams {public string Name; public int Age; public bool IsMale};
static Person CreatePersonByName(ref CreatePersonParams param)
{
  return new Person(param.Name, param.Age, param.IsMale);
}
... then to use it...
{
  ...
  CreatePersonParams newPersonParams;
  newPersonParams.Name = "Emily";
  newPersonParams.Age = 23;
  newPersonParams.IsMale = False;
  ...
  whatever = myDict.GetValueOrDefault(keyValue, CreatePersonByName, ref newPersonParams);
  ...
}
```

Note that creating a struct instance as a local variable is cheaper than creating a new class instance (essentially the same as creating a local variable for each of the struct fields).  Note also that because CreatePersonByName is a static method, the system only needs to create one delegate during the lifetime of the program.  Note further that passing structs by ref is cheap, no matter how big the structs are, and accessing the fields of structs passed by ref is just as efficient as accessing fields of a class.

Using this approach, the same `GetValueOrDefault` method can handle routines requiring any combination of parameters, without requiring the creation of any closures.  Unfortunately, because C# doesn't provide any language support this type of code transform (which could actually be simpler than the transformations of lambdas into closures) it's necessary to explicitly define all the types of structures one might want to use with it.  One could define a family of `TupleStruct<T1,T2,T3>` etc. structures and use those, but such a thing is still a little ugly.